# how to compare a password in symfony2 with fosuserbundle?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

this is my fuction code but iam get this error  Call to a member function get() on null. so help me please

```
public function verificarSenhaDefaultAction() {
        $a = "12345678";
        $default = $this->get('security.password_encoder')->encodePassword($this->getUser(), $a);

        if ($this->getUser()->getPassword() == $default):
            return TRUE;
        else:
            Return FALSE;
        endif;
    }
```

Comment: Are you expecting that encode password will update the user object?  Because it does not.  You need to call User::setPassword yourself.

Comment: not, i wont to make a compare the user password with '12345678'.

Comment: The error comes from the fact that you are doing something like $controller = new MyController() from (one assumes) a test somewhere.  The container is never getting set hence $this->get fails.  And once you get past this, getUser will fail as well.

Comment: so i did not get your answer very well, may you give some exemple more clear

Comment: Basically I an saying to read the manual (especially the sections on services and controllers) to get a bit more experience on how the framework actually works.  There is not a simple answer.  I suppose you could update your question with your actual testing code and someone could show you the specific issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call get function from the container like this:

```
$this->container->get('security.password_encoder')->encodePassword($this->getUser(), $a);
```

Comment: Which is not going to help since the container is not available in his test.

Answer (score 0):

For friendsofsymfony/UserBundle v2.0:

```
public function verificarSenhaDefaultAction(User $user, $password) {
    $encoder = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);

    return $encoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $password, $user->getSalt());
}
```